# ClojureScript ReFrame

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I create project by use https://github.com/day8/re-frame-template

Like: lein new re-frame my-project +10x +garden +test

And receive warnings:

```
------ WARNING #1 - :redef -----------------------------------------------------
 Resource: day8/re_frame_10x/inlined_deps/garden/v1v3v10/garden/color.cljc:390:1
 abs already refers to: cljs.core/abs being replaced by: day8.re-frame-10x.inlined-deps.garden.v1v3v10.garden.color/abs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------ WARNING #2 - :redef -----------------------------------------------------
 Resource: zprint/range.cljc:81:1
 abs already refers to: cljs.core/abs being replaced by: zprint.range/abs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------ WARNING #3 - :undeclared-var --------------------------------------------
 Resource: cljs/analyzer.cljc:4403:12
 Use of undeclared Var cljs.analyzer/Throwable
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------ WARNING #4 - :undeclared-var --------------------------------------------
 Resource: cljs/analyzer.cljc:4402:7
 Use of undeclared Var cljs.analyzer/ns-resolve
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 1st warning, try updating `re-frame-10x` to the latest version (`1.5.0` at the time of writing).

The 2nd warning - same for `zprint` (`1.2.4` now).

The 3rd and the 4th warnings - same for ClojureScript itself (if you're using shadow-cljs, update shadow-cljs instead).